# Ring theory square bracket notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, notation

What does the notation $[\mathfrak{p}]$ mean, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of some (polynomial) ring $A$ (parentheses because I'm not sure if $A$ being a polynomial ring is important) ?

Comment: where and in what context have you seen this notation?

Comment: @Stahl Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry, specifically in part 2, chapter 3 where he discusses the geometric visualisation of the complex affine line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vakil is using the notation $[\mathfrak{p}]$ to indicate the point in $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ corresponding to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A.$ He wants to distinguish between the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ as an ideal of the ring and as a point of the topological space $\operatorname{Spec}(A).$